# Interfacing MRCC with CFOUR for dynamic polarizability

Tags: coupled-cluster, mrcc, polarizability, answer-with-calculation

[I have asked this question on the MRCC forum](https://www.mrcc.hu/index.php/forum/search?query=dynamic&childforums=1) but did not get an answer.

I am trying to understand how to use CFOUR with the MRCC program for computing dynamic polarizability.  To begin with, I am trying the simple system of $\ce{H2}$.

The input passed to the CFOUR program is given below. This program finishes with error which is given in the second block.

```
hydrogen_molecule
H
H 1 R

R=1.41

*ACES2(CALC=CCSD,BASIS=AUG-PVQZ,CHARGE=0,PROP=DYNAMICAL
SCF_CONV=10
CC_PROGRAM=MRCC
INPUT_MRCC=ON
CC_CONV=10
LINEQ_CONV=10
DIFFTYPE=UNRELAXED
MEMORY=14
MEM_UNIT=GB)

%frequency
1
0.0856
```

---

Last few lines of the output file received.

```
.
.
.
  list                   233               1069156                  1034
                  1034
  list                   233                729316                   854
                   854
  list                   233               1483524                  1218
                  1218
  list                   233               1069156                  1034
                  1034
  list                   233               1069156                  1034
                  1034
  list                   233                729316                   854
                   854
         2874203179375         2874203179376         2874203180595
         2874203180613         2874203180614         2874203180706
         2874203180798
         2874203179375
 [   1]   -0.9440567
         2874203179375                     0                     0
 [   1]   -0.9440567
  scf energy  -1.02177241463266       0.375302907801333
         2874203179375         2874203179375         2874203179375
 [   1]   -0.9440567
  escf- ...  0.375302907801617
  escf- ...  -1.88811334095569       0.491038018521418
  itot is                      0
 using old mrcc fort.57
 fort.56
     2     1     0     0     1     3     0     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     0    11     0     0           0.08560     0 13351
ex.lev,nsing,ntrip, rest,CC/CI, dens,conver, symm, diag,  CS ,spatial,  HF ,ndoub,nacto,nactv, tol ,maxex, sacc, freq, dboc, mem
  @CHECKOUT-I, Total execution time :       5.9000 seconds.
                9.25 seconds walltime passed
 --executable xint finished with status            0
 --invoking executable dmrcc
 --executable dmrcc finished with status          127
```

The full output file is available [here](https://www.mrcc.hu/media/kunena/attachments/1612/H2_MRCC_new.txt).

Could someone clarify what would be the correct way to get this done?
(I can run test calculations if I receive suggestions.)

---

**Updates:**

1. Last few lines of `fort.55` file

   ```
           17                    46                    75
           86                    18                    92
           63                    41                    30
           87                    76                    64
           19                    65
   ```
2. Error in the dmrcc execution was found to be related to the compiler (`dmrcc: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_ilp64.so: cannot open shared object file`). After fixing it by setting the correct compilers before execution, the output received is [this](https://pastebin.com/i9buhwHD).
   Last few lines are shown below.

   Final results:
   Total CCSD energy [au]:              -1.080378012654

   Calculating reduced density-matrix for root 1...

   Total energy from RDM [au]:          -0.928161992158

   ************************ 2020-07-27 09:52:07 *************************
   Normal termination of mrcc.

   ---

   --executable dmrcc finished with status            0
   --invoking executable xdens
   CCSD density and intermediates are calculated.
   Unrelaxed density is calculated
   enter routine DINTERF to read densities generated from external sources
   two-particle density matrices
   D(I,J)
   0                     1                     1
   1                     1                     1
   1                     1                     0
   1                     1                     1
   1                     1                     1
   1                     1                    19
   30                    41                    46
   65                    76                    87
   1                    19                    30
   41                    46                    65
   76                    87                     0
   0                     0                     0
   0                     0                     0
   0                     1                     1
   DOO for spin                      1 -7.187996652958334E-002
   1                     1
   @RDDIR-F, I/O Error (IOSTAT =  25) on Unit  51.
   @CHECKOUT-I, Total execution time :       0.0000 seconds.
   --executable xdens finished with status            1

Comment: When you asked this on the MRCC forum, Mihaly Kallay (primary author of MRCC) told you to delete the MINP file, then you replied with a new message, where you say that you "supplied an MINP file". This output file that you're showing, has no error message. The last 2 lines say that you're running (invoking) `dmrcc` (which reads the MINP file) and then the `dmrcc` program finished. Since you're using `INPUT_MRCC=ON` please follow Mihaly's suggestion and remove your supplied MINP file. Otherwise, use `INPUT_MRCC=ON` and run `dmrcc` manually (not from CFOUR). Is there a `fort.55` file written?

Comment: I meant `OFF` not `ON` for the last `INPUT_MRCC` keyword. You used `ON` and the last sentence suggests a way to do it with `OFF`.

Comment: For the above execution, MINP file was not supplied. In the folder where the `xcfour` executable was run, there was only the input ZMAT file. As seen for the error in  `dmrcc` run, the error code 127 is received, I noticed that an error is also generated as `dmrcc: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_ilp64.so: cannot open shared object file`. I am looking into this now.

Comment: Okay, can you tell us whether or not a `fort.55` file was written by CFOUR, and if so can you post the last few lines of it please?

Comment: `fort.55` was written by CFOUR. The content (of last few lines) is shown in the question above now.

Comment: Perfect, and the last few lines look okay, so why don't you now run `dmrcc` on its own (manually)? This means, make a folder that has MINP and fort.55, and run `dmrcc` in that folder (make sure `iface=cfour` is still there in the MINP, to tell MRCC that it doesn't have to make fort.55 because CFOUR already did that).

Comment: After fixing the compiler error, the program runs longer and gives this output saying `Normal termination of mrcc`. Full output file will be attached with the question under updates.

Comment: What was the compiler error? Anyway, the problem is now with CFOUR, not MRCC. It's unable to finish writing the density matrix? I'll have to actually try to run your input file, but unfortunately I don't know where I can run it right now. I don't have access to any of my usual computers.

Comment: The compiler was not set correctly. I called `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
; source /opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64` before xcfour run, which fixed this error.

Comment: I would say this was a sourcing error rather than a compiler error. Anyway, I'll have to try to run your input file to see if I get anywhere. Sorry it will take a while because I don't have any computers at the moment.

Comment: The calculation is running for me. It's doing the CC iterations now.

Comment: If it helps at all, NWChem can do CCSD, CCSDT and CCSDTQ linear response dynamic polarizabilities with RHF, ROHF and UHF references. The CCSDT stuff is demonstrated in  http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.2929840. I didn't write a paper on the CCSDTQ stuff but it was used in http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3263604. Note that you need very strict convergence to get the same answer in both for CCSDTQ.

Comment: Jeff  Thanks for the information.

Comment: it looks like this option "PROP=DYNAMICAL" is not documented in the CFOUR manual. Do you know if one could calculate the properties for imaginary polarizabilities in CFOUR?

Comment: @Leo137 the user that posted this question has not logged into any SE site for about 10 days. Why don't you post your question separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got your calculation successfully completed:

```
  The final electronic energy is        -0.928161992153724 a.u.    This 
  computation required                          318.38 seconds (walltime).
```

My output (and input) files are [here](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/1715). They are the same as yours, except my ZMAT uses [my basis set database](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/AI_ENERGIES/blob/master/GENBAS), which I don't think will make a difference for you, since your output file did not complain about the basis set. If you want to try what I did, just run `xcfour` with my ZMAT file, and make sure you have my GENBAS file (hyperlinked above) in the same folder. Nothing else was different in my ZMAT.

I ran the job like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/pool/nike/MRCC
export PATH=/pool/dattani/MRCC:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/pool/nike/cfour_v2.00beta/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/pool/dattani/cfour_v2.00beta/bin

xclean
xcfour > out.1
```

These are the possible reasons why your job failed:

- You may want to run `xclean` before running CFOUR.
- I'm using CFOUR v2.00 Beta, and you're using CFOUR v1.2

Comment: Thanks. Your output does print out the asked property ( dynamic polarizability ) in the end. :-)